# How do I delay RxJava2 subscription?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code, which returns a lot of data in the response, so much that I get a NullPointerException when it's being loaded in the android Activity when I scroll down too fast (since not all the data has been initialized yet), no problems if I wait a second and then scroll.

I want a way to delay the `subscribe` part, so that the `Response<GetFeedTopicsResponseBody>` is entirely populated with data (none is not initialized) when I call `setAdapter`. I tried checking `response.isSuccessful` but that does not work because no problem with the response itself, just the data takes time to deserialize into Java objects from JSON. I also tried `onComplete` in `subscribe` but that does not work either.

So I want either a way in RxJava2 to have a boolean value switch to notify the following subscription once it is complete, it will subscribe.

```
        mGetFeedTopicsDisposable = ApiClient.getInstance()
            .doGetFeedTopicsQuery(request)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            .subscribe((Response<GetFeedTopicsResponseBody> response) -> {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    List<Topic> topics = response.body().getTopics();
                    if (topics != null) {
                        mBinding.fragmentTopicListRecyclerTopics.setAdapter(TopicListAdapter.getInstance(topics));
                        if (response.body().isPaginated()) {
                            mRequestBuilder.setCursor(response.body().getCursor());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, (Throwable ex) -> {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            });
```

The error message I specifically got was:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.models.User.getThumbnailImageUrl()' on a null object reference
```

where this `User` object is set as a field of the `Topic` object which is added into the list of topics retrieved with `getTopics()`. If I don't scroll, I don't get this `NullPointerException` and the thumbnail urls for the Users are loaded properly.

Comment: First thing comes in mind is the `delay` operator, did you try it? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

Comment: Can you post the error log? I think the issue is because you create your adapter in the response when you should create it before the call and then update the data in the adapter with the ones returned by the call

Comment: added error log

Comment: delaay does not work, I tried it

Comment: In order to delay the events you can, surprisingly, use `delay` operator. You tried it already and it didn't work but how exactly did you try?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Does your code have to correlate with another async call? What is the exact stacktrace of that NPE? What does `TopicListAdapter.getInstance` do?

Comment: @bycfly did you try my approach???

Answer (score 2):

Question : How do I delay RxJava2 Subscription?

Example :

I have added `repeat(...)` for better understanding.

```
io.reactivex.Observable
                    .just(new Object())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .repeat(2)
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("Delay Example ","Observer subscribed at : "+  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + " and execute after 10 seconds"))
                    .subscribe(new DefaultObserver<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Object o) {
                            Log.d("Delay Example ","on Next : "+  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.d("Delay Example ","on Complete : "+ DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
                        }
                    });
```

Output:

[image: log]

You see, on Next is called twice with 10 second delay.

Here, you can do adapter related operations in `onComplete`. :)

Hope this answers the question that you've asked.

Comment: Wow, let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: @bycfly _Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted._